# Pipes in replace causing line to be duplicated

Tags: powershell

I have a script that I need to replace a couple of lines in. The first replace is going fine but the second is wiping out my file and duplicating the line multiple times.

My code

```
(get-content $($sr)) -replace 'remoteapplicationname:s:SHAREDAPP',"remoteapplicationcmdline:s:$($sa)" | Out-File $($sr)
(get-content $($sr)) -replace 'remoteapplicationprogram:s:||SHAREDAPP',"remoteapplicationprogram:s:||$($sa)" | Out-File $($sr)
```

The first replace works perfectly. The second one is causing this:

> remoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredrremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagarederemoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagareddremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagarediremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredrremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagarederemoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredcremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredtremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredcremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredlremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagarediremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredpremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredbremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredoremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredaremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagaredrremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagareddremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagared:remoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagarediremoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagared:remoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagared1remoteapplicationprogram:s:||stagared
>   etc...

Is this because of the ||? If so, how do I get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: @Matt thank for the clarification. Any way around this? This is my first ps script so this is rather new to me.

Comment: There are several avenues to consider here but I will try to cover them briefly in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, you should be using slightly more meaningful names for your variables. Especially if you want someone else to be reviewing your code.

The gist of your issue is that `-replace` supports regexes (regular expressions), and you have regex control characters in your pattern string. Consider the following simple example, and notice everywhere the replacement string is found:

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> "ABCD" -replace "||", "bagel"
bagelAbagelBbagelCbagelDbagel
```

`-replace` is also an array operator, so it works on every line of the input file, which is nice. For simplicity's sake, if you are not using a regex, you should just consider using the string method `.Replace()`, but it is case-sensitive, so that might not be ideal. So let's escape those control characters in the easiest way possible:

```
$patternOne = [regex]::Escape('remoteapplicationname:s:SHAREDAPP')
$patternTwo = [regex]::Escape('remoteapplicationprogram:s:||SHAREDAPP')


(get-content $sr) -replace $patternOne, "remoteapplicationcmdline:s:$sa" | Out-File $($sr)
(get-content $sr) -replace $patternTwo, "remoteapplicationprogram:s:||$sa" | Out-File $($sr)
```

Now we get both patterns matched as you have them written. Run `$patternTwo` on the console to see what has changed to it! `$patternOne`, as written, has no regex control characters in it, but it does not hurt to use the escape method if you are just expecting simple matching.

---

Aside from the main issue pointed out, there is also some redundancy and misconception that can be addressed here. I presume you are updating a source file to replace all occurrences of those strings, yes? Well, you don't need to read the file in twice, given that you can chain `-replace`:

```
$patternOne = [regex]::Escape('remoteapplicationname:s:SHAREDAPP')
$patternTwo = [regex]::Escape('remoteapplicationprogram:s:||SHAREDAPP')

(get-content $sr) -replace $patternOne, "remoteapplicationcmdline:s:$sa" -replace $patternTwo, "remoteapplicationprogram:s:||$sa" | 
        Set-Content $sr
```

Perhaps that will do what you intended.

You might notice that I've removed the subexpressions operators (`$(...)`) around your variables. While they have their place, they don't need to be used here. They are only needed  inside more complicated strings, like when you need to expand object properties or something.

Comment: that is a great write up. I'll make note of what you said and adjust accordingly. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @ErocM Did this fix your issue then? You had a chance to test it

Comment: sure did! Thanks again!

Comment: @mklement0 That is funny since I even said in the answer that I had removed them. Editted.